# How to do twitter POST status/update method using Yahoo Pipes or YQL?

Tags: yahoo-pipes, yql, twitter-oauth

I want to update my twitter status using yahoo pipes. I could do that earlier without any difficulty using either yahoo pipes or YQL. But, recently I am not able to do it.
the document for POST status/update is http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update

Is there anyway to update status using yahoo pipes or YQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect so far you have been trying to update your Twitter status using simple Basic authentication, which Twitter has deprecated some time ago. To get it working again, [you need to start looking into OAuth authentication](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth). I have no idea if Yahoo Pipes or YQL support OAuth and how you would use that. That's up to you to find out.

Comment: Ya, u r right. I was using basic Auth. But i don't know what is Oauth. is it possible to do Oauth using Y! pipes or YQL??

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are a bunch of Twitter API endpoints that are mapped as YQL datatables.
e.g. [Twitter Search with YQL](http://y.ahoo.it/RjdrHjDh)

I have not used Oauth with the twitter datatables yet but in general you can us OAuth with YQL as well, so there should be no issue. Just search in the right hand side of the YQL console linked above for **twitter** and you will find all the mapped tables.

Comment: yes, YQL have it. But we need to register our application on twitter :( Is there any way upadte tuitter status using password and username only without resgistrating out app??

Comment: I don't think there is but why don't you just register one? It's free and easy.